# Are there vulgarities in Spanish that are universal throughout the language?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, vulgaridades

The vulgar words I'm familiar with all seem to be local slang. Does Spanish have any words that are universally accepted as vulgar or profane?

Comment: I almost asked a variation of this myself, but it seems like a list question to me.  I don't think it's the right format for an SE network site. :\  (too bad, because I'm really interested, so +1!  But, VtC.)

Comment: @Richard: To answer this question, a single example of a universally accepted vulgarity would be sufficient, not a complete list.

Comment: Of course there are universally accepted profane words in Spanish, although I'm not sure if it is acceptable to discuss them here...

Comment: It's not a list question. It's about existence. You don't have to provide a list to answer this question. A good answer would be something like "No there's definitely no words that are vulgar everywhere Spanish is spoken" and "Yes, off the top of my head I can think of the words XXX and YYY for instance".

Comment: @Richard: Although, a complete light might still be useful in another context. And while I also generally disapprove of list questions, it'll be a shame if we can't find a way to address this aspect of language that can be so important to those learning the language.

Comment: You can also link to a site or page off the site as one way to avoid including the profane words you don't want to write yourself.

Comment: Thinking things through and looking at the one response we've gotten, I can see that the way it's worded isn't a list question and probably won't be controversial.  The "universally accepted" narrows the scope far enough to be on the right side of "Not Constructive" (although it is still huge in scope). So, I voted to reopen.

Comment: Roberto Fontanarrosa, a wonderful writer talks about vulgarities in Spanish here (part 1/2) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErGLhqYJOrk. Don't miss him!

Comment: Most of the Spanish _universal vulgarities_ I remember are actually found in other Romance languages. Are those valid examples?

Comment: If you search in [RAE](http://www.rae.es/) you will see words that are official for that use but if you are looking for a vulgarity that all the people who speak spanish say you don't find because depending the place they have their own argot for this worlds. Sometimes is difficult for the spanish and latin people to understand all the argots.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is:

> Puta

is the perfect example. Widely recognized, even in Equatorian Guinea and in the Philippines.

Comment: Note that _puta_ or commonly _putang ina/putangina_ (lit. "bitch mother") are one of the most severe/rude ones in the Philippines.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that can count as quite universal. Being called woman-that-sells-sex is not nice anywhere I know.

Answer (score -3):

A vulgarism is a word or custom that degenerates the language, like adding an "s" at the end of the pronouns in the second person "TU" like "comprastes" , "vivistes", "hicistes"

so, long answer short : NO

in the moment a vulgarism is used widely is not a vulgarism anymore, is part of the language.

but if by vulgarism you mean insults, yeah there are plenty.

Comment: Vulgarities ≠ vulgarisms.  Vulgarities: another way of saying *profanity* or *palabrotas*.